# How to put a background image in a 2nd Frame?

Tags: python, python-2.7, tkinter

I need help. I need to bring out the image background to my new created frame in genkeymenu function. But the problem is, once the frame is created, the image background only seems to change in the first created frame. I tried to search for solutions but nothing works. Can I ask what's the problem?

```
import Tkinter as tk
from Tkinter import *
from PIL import Image, ImageTk



def genkeymenu():
    generatemenu = tk.Toplevel(mainmenu)

    bg1 = ImageTk.PhotoImage(file="key2.jpg")
    background_label = Label(image=bg1)
    background_label.place(x=0, y=0)
    background_label.image = bg1

    keynamelabel = Label(generatemenu, text="Enter your key name")

    keynameEntry = Entry(generatemenu)

    keynameButton = Button(generatemenu, text="Enter")


    check1024= Checkbutton(generatemenu, text="1024 bit")
    check2048= Checkbutton(generatemenu, text="2048 bit")
    check4096= Checkbutton(generatemenu, text="4096 bit")

    tk.background_label.grid(row=0)

    keynamelabel.grid(row=0)
    keynameEntry.grid(row=1)
    keynameButton.grid(row=2)

    check1024.grid(row=3, column=0)
    check2048.grid(row=3, column=1)
    check4096.grid(row=3, column=2)

    generatemenu.title("Generate Key")
    generatemenu.mainloop()


mainmenu = tk.Tk()

bg = ImageTk.PhotoImage(file="key.jpg")
background_label = Label(image=bg)
background_label.place(x=0, y=0)

genkeybutton = Button(mainmenu, text= "Generate Key Pair", fg="black", command=genkeymenu)
encryptbutton = Button(mainmenu, text= "Encrypt your message", fg="black")
decryptbutton = Button(mainmenu, text= "Decrypt your message", fg="black")

background_label.grid(row=0)

genkeybutton.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky = N, rowspan=2)

encryptbutton.grid(row=0, column=0)

decryptbutton.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky=S)

mainmenu.title("RSA ENCRYPTION")
mainmenu.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You specify all the widget to appear in the toplevel window but didn't do that for the background. `background_label = Label(generatemenu, image=bg1)`

```
import Tkinter as tk
from Tkinter import *
PIL import Image, ImageTk



def genkeymenu():
    generatemenu = tk.Toplevel(mainmenu)

    bg1 = ImageTk.PhotoImage(file="key2.jpg")
    background_label = Label(generatemenu, image=bg1)# specify the window you it to appear.
    background_label.place(x=0, y=0)
    background_label.image = bg1

    keynamelabel = Label(generatemenu, text="Enter your key name")

    keynameEntry = Entry(generatemenu)

    keynameButton = Button(generatemenu, text="Enter")


    check1024= Checkbutton(generatemenu, text="1024 bit")
    check2048= Checkbutton(generatemenu, text="2048 bit")
    check4096= Checkbutton(generatemenu, text="4096 bit")

    tk.background_label.grid(row=0)

    keynamelabel.grid(row=0)
    keynameEntry.grid(row=1)
    keynameButton.grid(row=2)

    check1024.grid(row=3, column=0)
    check2048.grid(row=3, column=1)
    check4096.grid(row=3, column=2)

    generatemenu.title("Generate Key")
    generatemenu.mainloop()


mainmenu = tk.Tk()

bg = ImageTk.PhotoImage(file="key.jpg")
background_label = Label(image=bg)
background_label.place(x=0, y=0)

genkeybutton = Button(mainmenu, text= "Generate Key Pair", fg="black", 
command=genkeymenu)
encryptbutton = Button(mainmenu, text= "Encrypt your message", fg="black")
decryptbutton = Button(mainmenu, text= "Decrypt your message", fg="black")

background_label.grid(row=0)

genkeybutton.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky = N, rowspan=2)

encryptbutton.grid(row=0, column=0)

decryptbutton.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky=S)

mainmenu.title("RSA ENCRYPTION")
mainmenu.mainloop()
```

Comment: Oh my totally didn't think of that. This works. Thank you!